# СПП с придаточным времени?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

*Шутки шутили до тех пор, пока не начали прибывать свежие части.*

Придаточное времени (союзы: до тех пор, пока), расчлененной структуры. Верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно, это СПП с придаточными времени. Соединительные элементы вы определили правильно.